# jQuery interact with text outputted before doctype declation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dom

I have a PHP application that is outputting a PHP notice. This is text simply shot out into the browser before anything else, including the DOCTYPE declaration.

```
    <br />
    <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined property: bla bla blap</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
    <!DOCTYPE html>
...regular web page
```

Is there a way to interact with this text using jQuery? It shows in the browser as the very first thing. How do you select the stuff above `<!DOCTYPE html>` in jQuery?

Comment: Surely it makes more sense to fix the line causing the message? If you really don't want to (or can't) do that, you could use output buffering to prevent the message being output before the start of the HTML.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Nick - I need to use jQuery specifically to modify the PHP notice. I'm looking for a generalized solution, so there is no way to fix the specific PHP error because I don't know what it is.

Comment: Twisty, this is a complete example. I'm looking for how to select text outputted from PHP BEFORE the DOM. Specifically, this is exactly how PHP outputs "notices" and "errors". Is there a way to select this text with jQuery once it's rendered in the browser. How do you select the stuff above the <!DOCTYPE

Comment: disable error output. It's not very secure letting people see various errors

Comment: charlietfl - I want to use jQuery to catch the error. I cannot disable PHP error reporting from jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the elements using `$('body').contents()` because the browser interprets them as elements of the body. When the browser sees text before the doctype declaration, it shifts that text and the contents of the head into the body as it's way of trying to build a viable DOM even though the html was not valid.

Since the browser has reorganized the content, you cannot guess what the first element of the head was supposed to be. This script lets you set the element that was supposed to be the first element of the head. The script will then access the elements before the one you set and provides you with information regarding whether the element is a text node or DOM element.

You have to interact with the text nodes using vanilla js but you can use jQuery for the others.

```
// the script needs to know what should have been the first element in the head
const firstElementInHead = $( 'title' );
// remove all nodes prior to the intended content
$('body').contents().each( function() {
    if ( $(this).index() < firstElementInHead.index() ) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

```html
<br />
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined property: bla bla blap on line <b>16</b><br />
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>The Broken Page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // the script needs to know what should have been the first element in the head
    const firstElementInHead = $('title');
    // log the nodes that apear prior to the intended content
    $('body').contents().each(function() {
      if ($(this).index() < firstElementInHead.index()) {
        if (this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
          console.log('This is a text node. You can change it by setting this.nodeValue, remove it by calling this.remove(), or other vanilla JS operations.');
          console.log(this);
        } else {
          console.log('This is a DOM element. You can interact with it using jQuery the same way you interact with any normal DOM element.');
          console.log(this);
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body style="padding:0; margin:0;">
  <p style="padding:0; margin:0; background:red;">Test</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This script chops off everything above whatever you select as `firstElementInHead` and in this case I use `$('title')` but you may need to use `$('meta:first-of-type')` or a script or link tag.

Comment: My initial code interacts with it by calling .remove(). You can do what ever you want with those nodes, but some of them are not jquery elements, they are text nodes.

Comment: The browser is what is scraping the doctype out. I've updated the script and the answer to try and clarify why this is tricky and what you can do to manipulate those elements. Load this html in a local page rather that in the sandboxed iframe snippet to really see what is happening in the browser.

Comment: Awesome job! Thank you for explaining it.

Comment: Right on, and truthfully I hope you're able to fix the error on the php side and that you won't need to use any of this stuff!